# profile page do not work after submitting the login process

Tags: php, mysql, apache, session

i  have a login page that allow user to enter email and password after checking if data correct the browser must display the profile page but the problem is that after i enter email and password the system freeze and do not display the profile page even if the data are true .

but if i echo a message that inform the user the data are correct the browser display this message   can anyone help me ??? plz i had tried from 2 days until now without any success and no one had give me the right solution.

i figure out what is the error but i do not know how to fix it

```
 if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        **header("location:index.php");**
    }
    //var_dump($login_user);

   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $id = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $firstname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lastname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
```

plz try my code and anyone tell me what it is wrongg

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('include/connect.php');
$message = ""; 
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
{

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$email = strip_tags($email);
$pass = strip_tags($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
//$pass = md5($pass);

$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)
  {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

          $id = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

          $firstname = $row['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

          $email = $row['email_address'];
          $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

          mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

        //$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
          header("Location: profile.php");
         // exit();   
  }//close if 
  else
  {
      $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
      //exit();
  }
}//close if
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

## profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 require_once('include/connect.php'); 


if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['user_id'];
    var_dump($id);

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

else
{
    print "Important  data  are missing";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    exit();

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   $firstname=$row['first_name'];
   $lastname=$row['last_name'];
   $birth_date=$row['birth_date'];
   $registered_date=$row['registered_date'];
   //***************for upload img*****************//
   $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"100px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\">";
   }
   echo $id, $firstname, $birth_date;
?>
```

## header.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    //var_dump($login_user);

   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $id = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $firstname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lastname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="banner">
  <div class="img-border">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="header">

        <div id="logo">
          <marquee width="80%">
            <h1><b>Social Media Network</b></h1>
          </marquee>
        </div>
         <div id="menu">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="profile.php" accesskey="1" title=""><?php echo $login_user ?>'s Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="update_account.php" accesskey="2" title="">Update</a></li>
                <li><a href="search.php" accesskey="3" title="">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="map.php" accesskey="4" title="">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback_form.php" accesskey="4" title="">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="help.php" accesskey="6" title="">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php" accesskey="7" title="">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/web_header copy.jpg" width="1121" height="210" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## in the apache error log

```
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\new adamKhoury\\profile.php:0, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. require_once() C:\\wamp\\www\\new adamKhoury\\profile.php:181, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: last_name in C:\\wamp\\www\\new adamKhoury\\header.php on line 13, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\new adamKhoury\\profile.php:0, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. require_once() C:\\wamp\\www\\new adamKhoury\\profile.php:181, referer: http://localhost/new%20adamKhoury/index.php
[Wed May 08 08:19:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Do not give `localhost` in header location. And keep `exit` after header redirect.

Comment: Check your errors add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on top of the file.

Comment: @Rikesh, `display_errors` is not being set with `ini_set`. it should be set in `php.ini`

Comment: @user, change `display_errors` directive to `on` in your `php.ini`, restart apache,and see all errors and warnings on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your header.php script which causes your system to quit. Watch for the `last_name` on line 13, it doesn't exist and i'm guessing it has something to do with it. Not only do you output data before the headers are sent, even notices should be fixed :)

Comment: There's no session start in header.php, so you lost your session on the way?

Comment: i did add the session_start() in the header  but still not workinggggg

Comment: i figure out what is the error but i do not know how to fix it   if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
  **header("location:index.php");**
 }
 //var_dump($login_user);

   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $id = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $firstname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lastname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);

Answer (score 0):

Remove localhost from header. It should be like `header("Location: profile.php");`

Comment: Or use the full URL, as in http://localhost/. The current way (`header("Location: localhost/profile.php");`) is processed as a directory probably

Comment: oh sorry it must be a mistake because the header is without the localhost

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this in header can you replace following code

```
header("Location: http://localhost/profile.php");
```

if it won't work try below -->

can you remove localhost and just keep /profile.php in header

if login.php and profile.php in same folder try this ->

replace `header("Location: localhost/profile.php");` with `header("Location: /profile.php");`

else

replace `header("Location: localhost/profile.php");` with `header("Location: /<pathfromlogin.php>/profile.php");` ex. `header("Location: /info/user/profile.php");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with URL you given in the header location 
replace your header like below

```
 header("Location: http://localhost/profile.php");
```